# Footer with JQuery Problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, footer

I am using the following html/jquery to try and get a footer that expands when moused-over (see code below). Instead the footer stays in the same place and does not expand at all. (CSS at bottom).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="v_line"></div>
    <div class="column">
        <ul id="lpro">  <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="googleme">  
                <img src="google.png" alt="google_filler"></div></a>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <ul id="spro">  <a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank"><div class="yahoo"><img   
                 src="yahoo.png" alt="yahoo_filler"></div></a>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript (with JQuery):**

```
function openmenu(e) {
    if (e) e.stopPropagation();
    $('#footer').animate({
        height: "75px"
    }, 400, null, function () {
        $("#footer").off("mouseenter");
        $('#footer').on('mouseleave', closemenu);
    });
}

function closemenu(e) {
    if (e) e.stopPropagation();
    $('#footer').animate({
        height: "33px"
    }, e ? 400 : 0, null, function () {
        $("#footer").off("mouseleave");
        $('#footer').on('mouseenter', openmenu);
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('#footer').on('mouseenter', openmenu);
    closemenu();
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

**Footer CSS:**

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background-color:#0F0F0F;
    height:150px;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: Could you put it into a JSFiddle?

Comment: This is why HTML/CSS sux.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/9ZNdc/ , works well here , what exactly is the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

You definitely don't need Javascript for this. Try css:

```
#footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  background-color:#0F0F0F;
  height:33px;
  opacity:0.8;
  transition: height 400ms;
}

#footer:hover {
  height: 150px;
}
```

You'd do better to animate something like `translate` for performance though, like so:

```
#footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  background-color:#0F0F0F;
  height:150px;
  opacity:0.8;
  transform: translateY(120px);
  transition: transform 400ms;
}

#footer:hover {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script works for me.
The only thing I changed (from your pre-edit version) was the jquery link.

If the site is on a live server, try changing

```
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
```

to

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in order to make sure you are loading the latest version.